# Windows DNS answers NXDOMAIN for local zone from VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, vpn

### Note: Wrong assumptions

It turned out that the VPN is configured to redirect all name lookups to a different server. So the problem is not the Windows DNS but the VPN Gateway.

### Original Quesiton

I have a remote network 10.12.0.0/16 with a Windows Domain Controller (SBS 2011) and a VPN Gateway. Some Windows PC (no domain member) uses a l2tp VPN to connect to the SBS. It gets a virtual IP in 10.14.0.0/24. The VPN gateway is the SBS's default gateway and routes between the two networks. SBS and client can ping each other.

The Domain Controller owns the Active Directory Domain `company.local`. If I nslookup it on the SBS it is correctly resolved to the IP of the SBS. A query from the VPN Gateway works as well. But a `nslookup company.local 10.12.0.5` (later is the SBS IP) from the client will respond that the domain is not found. Via tcpdump on the VPN gateway I can see that the SBS really returns `NXDOMAIN 0/0/0`.

As you might already guess the goal is to join the domain with the VPN connected computer.

Why does the DNS Server not return the correct A Record? My only idea is that the query comes from an unknown private network.

### Update 01

Full query from the client computer:

```
C:\Users\abc>nslookup -debug company.local 10.12.0.5
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        5.0.12.10.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  5.0.12.10.in-addr.arpa
        name = xyz.cloud.internal
        ttl = 0 (0 secs)

------------
Server:  xyz.cloud.internal
Address:  10.12.0.5

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        company.local, type = A, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        company.local, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        company.local, type = A, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        company.local, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
*** xyz.cloud.internal can't find company.local: Non-existent domain
```

### Update 02

```
C:\Users\abc>nslookup -debug _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.company.local.
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        5.0.12.10.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  5.0.12.10.in-addr.arpa
        name = xyz.cloud.internal
        ttl = 0 (0 secs)

------------
Server:  xyz.cloud.internal
Address:  10.12.0.5

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.company.local, type = A, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.company.local, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  (root)
        ttl = 10789 (2 hours 59 mins 49 secs)
        primary name server = a.root-servers.net
        responsible mail addr = nstld.verisign-grs.com
        serial  = 2013011600
        refresh = 1800 (30 mins)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 86400 (1 day)

------------
*** xyz.cloud.internal can't find _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.company.local.: Non-existent domain
```

Comment: Two things: 1. To simplify your troubleshooting simply turn on debugging in nslookup on the client (set debug). That way you'll see the full query and the full answer without having to run a tcpdump. You'll clearly see the NXDOMAIN returned from the server in nslookup with debug turned on. 2. After setting debug you'll see the full query from the client. Hopefully that wqill give you some insight.

Comment: If you do the same nslookup from a client that is on the same subnet, does it respond as you would expect?

Comment: @CodingGorilla - Off topic. Apologies. It's been awhile. Good to see you.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks for the debug tip. I see 4 requests (2 identical queries for A and AAAA). Each answered with NXDOMAIN. Unfortunately I have no other windows computer in this network right now. But the `dig @10.12.0.5 company.local` on the VPN gateway returns the A record fine.

Comment: The answer headers:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the nslookup query and answer with set debug on?

Comment: @joeqwerty I updated the question

Comment: I'm not sure if this is just because you were trying to obfuscate some of the names or not, but I notice the server is `xyz.cloud.internal`, but you are querying for `company.local`.  Is this server authoritative for `company.local`?

Comment: @Thomas BTW, FWIW, when you're adding a workstation to a domain, it's actually going to query for something like `gc._msds.company.local`.  So you might be chasing the wrong rabbit.

Comment: @CodingGorilla What you noticed is right. There are two domains. The reverse DNS is handled by the VPN gateway. The `company.local` is anonymized but the SBS is authoritative for it. It's the SBS domain. I also ran a query for `gc._msds.company.local` and was a bit surprised that I got a forwarded NXDOMAIN from one of the root servers.

Comment: @Thomas I think that's your problem, I think your client is actually querying the wrong servers (which is very common with VPNs). Just as an experiment, remove the primary/secondary DNS settings from your internet connection (after the VPN is connected obviously) and then try to join the domain and see what happens.

Comment: I agree with @CodingGorilla - There's a mismatch between the server DNS suffix and the DNS suffix you're querying for: company.internal versus company.local. If the zone is named company.internal and the server doesn't have a zone named company.local then that would explain the failure. Are you assigning the DNS suffix to the VPN client via DHCP? If so, my guess is that you're assigning the wrong DNS suffix.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I know DNS server selection could be difficult. But I am sure the windows client queries the remote SBS. I see the DNS request to `_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.company.local.`in the tcpdump. I also tried to configure the local network of the client without any DNS server.

Comment: @Thomas Can you make that query and get a result?

Comment: @joeqwerty The reverse DNS `*cloud.internal` is provided by the infrastructure. I cannot change this. The forward DNS is really `company.local` (company beeing some other valid ascii name). The SBS owns this zone as normal. There is no DNS suffix assigned on VPN dialin. I do also check again `company.local.` to ensure it's no suffix problem.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I added the query to the question

Comment: @Thomas Is it possible that the VPN is intercepting/modifying the DNS queries?  Can you do the same query on the local network and have it return the proper results?

Comment: @CodingGorilla same query on the domain controller and the VPN Gateway give proper authoritative answers.

Comment: @CodingGorilla regarding intercepting queries. This is not the case. I see on the gateway that the SBS answers the queries. Bu instead of the correct records it responds with NXDOMAIN.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry then, outside of any crazy permissions, I'm completely out of ideas.  If the only goal is to get this workstation on the domain, then you could of course fake it all by adding the appropriate entries into the HOSTS file.  That's a major hack, but if it gets you where you need to be then I would go ahead and do it.

Comment: @CodingGorilla My appologies. I just noticed that I was wrong when I said that the SBS answers with NXDOMAIN. In fact the VPN Gateway internally redirects the UDP port 53 traffic to itself. I noticed it by using a packet sniffer on the SBS. So I guess I have to find an alternative VPN solution - that's bad. But thanks anyway to both of you.

Comment: @Thomas At least you have been able to identify the source of the problem, maybe there's a way to turn that feature off on the VPN or reconfigure it to forward the DNS queries properly.  Either way, good luck.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Thanks. If you like paste your question from above as solution. That's basically the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as troublehsot in the comments) ends up being the VPN gateway was intercepting the DNS queries.